# Jquery dynamic fileds generation

Tags: jquery

In the following code .How can i dynamically generate textboxes bellow the add and del button insted of displaying below the job details heading.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7uQx/15/)

**HTML:**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;" align="right">Name
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Job Name" value="" />
            </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Versions</td>
        <td>
            <select id="version" style="width:350px;">
                <option value="">SELECT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Test Scripts</td>
        <td>
            <select id="testscripts" style="width:350px;"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">datas</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="AddTables();" />
            <input type="button" id="del" value="Del" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:3px" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #383838">
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="adde" value="New" onclick="clearData();" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" id="edit" value="Save" onclick="saveToDB();"
            />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteData();"
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <h2>Job Details</h2>

            <div id="navcont" style="width: 880px; height: 5px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; list-style: none; float: left;background-color: #383838"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <!-- TODO:change this as div, create table inside helper script-->
            <div id="jobsTable"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    if (table.find('input:text').length < 7) {
        table.append('<tr><td style="width:200px;" align="right">First Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td><td style="width:200px;" align="right">Last Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td></tr>');
    }
});
$('#del').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    if (table.find('input:text').length > 1) {
        table.find('input:text').last().closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/x7uQx/16/)**

try this code

```
 $('#add').click(function () {
     var table = $(this).closest('table');
     if (table.find('input:text').length < 7) {
         $('<tr><td style="width:200px;" align="right">First Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td><td style="width:200px;" align="right">Last Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give ID to the `<td align="right">datas</td>` and than append HTML to it.
Do the formatting for how you wan to display.

Thing is you use append correctly on any html element, so it appends where you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following technique

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    if (table.find('input:text').length < 7) {
        tr.after('<tr><td style="width:200px;" align="right">First Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td><td style="width:200px;" align="right">Last Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Notice, I took the parent `tr` of the buttons and used it as a reference point to add tr right next to it instead of adding to the end of table.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var table = $(this).closest('table');
if (table.find('input:text').length < 7) {
    table.find('tr:last').after('<tr><td style="width:200px;" align="right">First Name <td> <input type="text" value="" /> </td><td style="width:200px;" align="right">Last Name <td> <input type="text" value="" /> </td></tr>');
}
```

also, i think its not right to give each inputs the same id's